# Can't iterate child from real-time database firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm tried to Get a nested child from my DB here's a structure

[image: DB]

I want to to get the **URI** from Gallery object
when I log in I can see this in console

[image: Console]
here is a code:

```
componentWillMount() {
    const { gKey } = this.state;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${gKey}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(async snapshot => {
        let aboutMe = snapshot.val().aboutMe;
        let uri = snapshot.val().galary;
        await this.setState({ aboutMe });
        console.log(uri);
        uri.forEach(childNodes => {
          console.log(childNodes); // I Got Error here
        });
      });
}
```

Error I got

> uri.forEach is not a function

### Update

I Got all the URI in a parent "Gallery" and set it in an array and pass it into a Component as a prop Now in this Component and render it in an  I just see one Image of theme !!

**Parent Screen**

```
Class Parent extend Component{
constructor(props){
super(props)
 this.state={
        ...
        images:[], 
        aboutMe:""
        ...
}


    componentWillMount() {
    const { gKey } = this.state;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${gKey}`)
      .once("value")
      .then(async snapshot => {
        let aboutMe = snapshot.val().aboutMe;
        let uri = snapshot.val().galary;
        await this.setState({ aboutMe });
        Object.values(uri).forEach(childNodes => {
          let images = [];
          images.push({
            uri: childNodes.uri
          });
          this.setState({ images });
        });
      });
}

render(){
return(
<View>
....
<GalaryScreen images={this.state.images} />
....
</View>
)}
}
```

[image: Galary]

**Galary.js**

```
class GalaryScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, padding: 10, color: "#000" }}>Galary</Text>
        <FlatList
          horizontal
          key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
          data={this.props.images}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            console.log(item.uri); // I can see every url here and all of them is a vaild URL 
            return (
              <View style={{ margin: 10 }}>
                <Image
                  key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
                  style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
                  source={{ uri: item.uri }}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.key}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GalaryScreen;
```

**Console**

[image: Console]

Comment: Can you add the code for the component that fetches the data and then passes it to the GalaryScreen component?

Comment: Check it again, @TreyEckels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is here:

```js
Object.values(uri).forEach(childNodes => {
          let images = [];
          images.push({
            uri: childNodes.uri
          });
          this.setState({ images });
        });
```

`let images = [];` is inside your `forEach` loop so it's always only going to hold 1 image on every iteration. Try declaring the images array outside of the loop and `setState` after you exit the loop. You want to do something more like:

```js
let images = [] 
Object.values(uri).forEach(childNodes => { images.push({ uri: childNodes.uri }); }); 
this.setState({ images });
```

Comment: Yeah , i'm already do it but it's my bad I'm forget to added it ` let images=[] ` and push every image to these and if you see in galary console I can see every uri

Comment: You can see every URI in the console because state changes each time, so the gallery code renders every time, the console code runs every time. The image in the gallery is changing every time too but it's happening so fast you don't see it. Can you show us the code with `let images` and where you push this in?

Comment: Check it agian @TreyEckels

Comment: `let images = [];` is inside your forEach loop so it's always only going to hold 1 image on every iteration. Try declaring the images array outside of the loop and setState after you exit the loop. You want to do something more like:
`let images = []
Object.values(uri).forEach(childNodes => {
          images.push({
            uri: childNodes.uri
          });
        });
this.setState({ images });`

Comment: UH OH, That's a big mistake! Yeah, That's what I want, Now at first you said a **" side note "**, that's for my code or in general?

Comment: @JohnS, it was just in general.

Comment: Anyway Thanks, If you can edit your answer and I will make it as Accepted!

Comment: Can you check this for me, please, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57236861/how-to-save-object-of-images-to-real-time-firebase @TreyEckels

Answer (score 0):

forEach is used for `Arrays` not for `Objects`

If you want to loop trough that object you have to do :

```
Object.values(uri).forEach(childNodes=>{
   console.log(childNodes); 
});
```

EDIT.

`forEach` is exclusive to `arrays` and has never been available for objects.

If you have were able to do uri.forEach in the past than something changed server side and now return an object instead of an array.

Explaining my code:

Object.values returns an array of all the values inside that object
for example:

```
const obj={a:"1",b:"2"}
Object.values(obj) .  //returns [ "1" , "2"]
```

After that did a forEach as your code were before.

Comment: Can you check the Update please, @Auticcat

Comment: Hey, Again I have a **Promise Object** how to get the specific value of them @Auticcat , https://i.imgur.com/zth4wd5.png